# Canvas to app, screen resize?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have made a game that is 800x300.

Now I was just wondering if I wanted to make it into an app for the app stores would it be possible at this screen size? or would I have to re-size based on screen size, in which case I would have to edit my code :(

As for it being html5 can you make much money as the code can only be made confusing.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "As for it being html5 can you make much money as the code can only be made confusing."

Comment: It's easier to "steal" code when it's there in the browser, but that doesn't mean it can be used. You need to choose the right license for your app to limit its usage. There is no way to protect *any* software from piracy or from de-compiling (you could run everything as a SaS, but that requires costly server infrastructure and there would still be a risk..). Potential piracy is something you need to calculate into the cost. My 2 cents..

Answer (score 0):

You can scale canvas elements using css.
If you create a canvas element and set its height and width attributes to 800x300, you can then use css to set its **CSS h/w** to the scaled size.
ex:
    `<canvas height="300" width="800" style="height:100%;width:100%"></canvas>`

Comment: Using css to resize a canvas will often distort any further drawings, so instead use javascript to change the width/height of the canvas element: myCanvas.width=300 and myCanvas.height=800.  ;)